# What's the difference between the battery of iPhone 5s vs iPhone 5?

Tags: battery, iphone

Do they have the same capacity and/or run time for certain identical tasks?

I know **iPhone 5**'s battery has a charge capacity of [1440mAh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_5#Hardware). Has this been improved in the new **iPhone 5s** and/or **iPhone 5c**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are slight improvements to the battery capacities of the 5S and 5C over the 5.

- iPhone 5 - 1440mAh <- 5.45Whr at 3.8V
- iPhone 5c - 1508mAh <- 5.73Whr at 3.8V
- iPhone 5s - 1558mAh <- 5.92Whr at 3.8V

[Source](http://iexpertsaustralia.blogspot.com/2013/09/iphone-55s5c-teardown.html)

---

In terms of battery life comparison for 5 vs. 5c vs. 5s, they ran some benchmarks in [their review](http://www.anandtech.com/show/7335/the-iphone-5s-review/9).  In some tasks the 5c/5s are better than the 5, in others the 5 is better.  With the exception of their Wifi browsing test, the new phones are comparable to the 5, with there being less than an hour difference in battery life.  In the Wifi browsing test though, the new phones ran out of juice .57 hours sooner (5c) and 1.3 hours sooner (5s).

Answer (score -1):

During the keynote, Phil Schiller stated that the battery on the iPhone 5C was slightly larger than the battery on the current iPhone 5, and the [Apple iPhone compare page](http://www.apple.com/iphone/compare/) states the same battery life for the 5C and the 5S, so I suspect they may have the same battery.

Comment: 5S and 5C with the same battery? What about 5C/S comparing to 5? Would like to know what slightly larger means... Can't find that info anywhere.

Comment: Ah. You simply asked whether or not it had been improved.

Comment: If the "charge capacity of 1440mAh" has improved. This is what I want to know. Concrete numbers (but maybe they haven't been released yet).